# Why are some box-shadow not shown with Safari?

Tags: html, css, safari, box-shadow

Box shadows with decimal are sometimes not displayed with Safari?

How can I fix it?

Here is an code example.

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0.0351725rem 0.0351725rem 0px, 0px 0px 0px 0.0175862rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check the `issues` tab on https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-boxshadow

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I don't know if it is a good practice to use so much numbers after decimal point. But you do what you need to do.

About your problem.

Try to add another box-shadow property with prefix -webkit-.
It should look like this:

```
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0.0351725rem 0.0351725rem 0px, 0px 0px 0px 0.0175862rem;
```

More about prefixes in [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Vendor_Prefix)